# C# XNA Movement - Can either turn or move, not both

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics

I'm trying to make an XNA spaceship game, where I can turn, and fire guns and such. I ran into a problem trying to get it so that I can give a ship a waypoint. For some reason, I can get the ship to move, or I can get it to turn, but I can't seem to get it to do both at once. It's really strange.

Basically, if I comment out my rotation code, it will fly straight, otherwise it will turn, but it doesn't move it just stays in place.

```
 if (GoToWayPoint == true)
 {

     //CurrentWayPoint.Normalize();
     Pos.Normalize();

     float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(CurrentWayPoint.X - Pos.X, CurrentWayPoint.Y - Pos.Y);

     //Rotate if 
     if (Rotation > angle && Rotation - TurnSpeed >= angle)
     {
         Rotation -= TurnSpeed;
     }
     else if (Rotation < angle && Rotation + TurnSpeed <= angle)
     {
         Rotation += TurnSpeed;
     }
     else
     {
         Rotation = angle;
     }

     //Move forward if it's facing the right direction
     if (Rotation == angle)
     {
         Velocity.X += (float)Math.Cos(Rotation) * TangentialVelocity * Speed;
         Velocity.Y += (float)Math.Sin(Rotation) * TangentialVelocity * Speed;
     }        

     if (Pos == CurrentWayPoint || Vector2.Distance(Pos,CurrentWayPoint) < 10)
     {
         Pos = CurrentWayPoint;

         GoToWayPoint = false;
     }

 }

 //Movement, player controlled
 if (PlayerControlled == true)
 {
     KeyboardState NewKey = Keyboard.GetState();

     //Move Up
     if (NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
     {
         Velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(Rotation) * TangentialVelocity * Speed;
         Velocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(Rotation) * TangentialVelocity * Speed;
     }

     //Move Down
     if (NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
     {
         Velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(Rotation + Math.PI) * TangentialVelocity;
         Velocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(Rotation + Math.PI) * TangentialVelocity;
     }

     //Move Right
     if (NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
     {
         Rotation += TurnSpeed;
     }

     //Move Left
     if (NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || NewKey.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
     {
         Rotation -= TurnSpeed;
     }
}

//Update Movement
Pos += Velocity;

//Friction
float i = Velocity.X;
float j = Velocity.Y;

Velocity.X = i -= Friction * i;
Velocity.Y = j -= Friction * j;
```

Additionally, I have code where I can control the GameObject using the arrow keys. That code works fine, and uses the same type code for moving forward.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that you don't have to evaluate that conditional by doing `(GoToWayPoint == true)`. `GoToWayPoint` will evaluate to true or false by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies mostly in this line:

```
if (Rotation == angle)
```

Your ship will only go forward when that conditional evaluates to `true`. Unfortunately it will never be true, because angle is a `float`. It is very hard to get two floating point numbers to equal each other unless you specifically assign them the same value (There are other ways, but they're irrelevant in this case).

You calculate `angle` here:

```
float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(CurrentWayPoint.X - Pos.X, CurrentWayPoint.Y - Pos.Y);
```

This will in all likelihood give you a value with a lot of digits after the decimal point, like `1.519573617...`. On top of that, you're only turning your ship by some fixed amount, `TurnSpeed`, which will always skip over your precise directional value, change angular direction, and skip over it again, ad infinitum. That's why you never go forward.

There are two solutions I can think of off the top of my head that you can try:

One is to lose the if-statement up there. Then your craft will start going, albeit in the wrong direction, but it will adjust its direction as it moves.

The other is to use an epsilon to compare `Rotation` with `angle`. It would look like this:

```
if (Math.Abs(Rotation - angle) < epsilon)
{
    Rotation = angle;
    // move forward
}
```

This gives you a bit of wiggle room when comparing the floats, namely an `epsilon` amount of wiggle room. It will have to be large enough so that your `TurnSpeed` won't jump over the entire interval, but small enough so that it's not too noticeably different from the exact direction.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that you're using rotation to move and shoot. More precisely, you are using the same angle for shooting and moving.

You have two solutions:

1st, move ships position up/down/left/right without use of angle. That means code will be something like `if(key up is pressed) ship.position.Y -= ship.speed;`. This means you freed the angle for drawing and shooting.

2nd, create new angle variable for the ship. Now you have two (lets say `moveAngle` and `shootAngle`). So, when you're moving the ship use moveAngle, and when you need to calculate where to shoot, use shootAngle. Now all thats left is for you to choose which angle you'll use for drawing.

Bonus: Use leftand right keys to strafe 90 degrees from where the ship's looking.